# c# OpenXML error with Word Online files: Absolute URIs are not supported

Tags: c#, ms-word, uri, openxml

I'm currently working with OpenXml.Wordprocessing to handle docx files, created with Word Online.
With a docx file saved with Word (not online) I have no problem for the command:

```
using (var wdDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
```

If I use the same docx file but saved with Word Online, I have the following error:
**targetUri Parameter name: Absolute URIs are not supported**

Running some tests with debugger I have noticed that the problematic URI could be word/document.xml, but I have no idea in which way I can fix this stuff.

Here the stacktrace:

*"  at System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri (System.Uri sourcePartUri, System.Uri targetUri) [0x0001a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackUriHelper.cs:195 \n  at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.LoadReferencedPartsAndRelationships (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart sourcePart, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.RelationshipCollection relationshipCollection, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] loadedParts) [0x00098] in <4ab5d094c38a4200ae0a70753476e093>:0 \n  at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart.Load (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart parent, System.Uri uriTarget, System.String id, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] loadedParts) [0x000fc] in <4ab5d094c38a4200ae0a70753476e093>:0 \n  at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.LoadReferencedPartsAndRelationships (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart sourcePart, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.RelationshipCollection relationshipCollection, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] loadedParts) [0x0016e] in <4ab5d094c38a4200ae0a70753476e093>:0 \n  at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Load () [0x000f5] in <4ab5d094c38a4200ae0a70753476e093>:0 \n  at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.OpenCore (System.String path, System.Boolean readWriteMode) [0x0004d] in <4ab5d094c38a4200ae0a70753476e093>:0 \n  at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Open (System.String path, System.Boolean isEditable, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenSettings openSettings) [0x000a6] in <4ab5d094c38a4200ae0a70753476e093>:0 \n  at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Open (System.String path, System.Boolean isEditable) [0x00007] in <4ab5d094c38a4200ae0a70753476e093>:0 \n*

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after several debugging sessions this seems to be a problem of mono itself.
This is an open bug with the implementation of the Uri package.
Using an environment variable **MONO_URI_DOTNETRELATIVEORABSOLUTE=true mono app.exe** the problem was solved, following http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/known-issues/urikind-relativeorabsolute/